# How to connect multiple socket.io clients to different URLs in Node.js?

Tags: url, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect many socket.io clients for different URLs in Node.js like so :

```
app.get('/:id',function(req,res){
io.of('/'+id).on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.emit('hello');

})
});
```

This works however there is a problem :

When a browser refreshs the page http://localhost:3000/xyz for example, the event socket.emit gets fired two times.

If someone accesses the page http://localhost:3000/xyz 10 times, then the event fires 10 times.

This is not good because everytime the user visits that page, the socket events will be fired n+1 times.

What should be done so that I can register sockets to different URLs and at the same time not have this anomaly .

Another thing :

If I do this  :

```
var sock;

io.of('/'+xyz).on('connection',function(socket){
    sock=socket;

})


app.get('/:id',function(req,res){
    sock.emit('hello');

})
```

If I use the above code then the socket doesn't get saved succesfully to the **sock** variable in *time*. What that means is , I have to do a setInterval of about 1000 .. so that the

```
sock=socket
```

line gets fired.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with this, in each request to http://localhost:3000/id, you register a new handler, you should be doing that once, not at every request.

```
app.get('/:id',function(req,res){
    io.of('/'+id).on('connection',function(socket){
        socket.emit('hello');

    })
});
```

Comment: Yes I know that .. but what is the solution for my usecase ?

Comment: Your approahc is wrong, you have to store id-socket relationship, and emit an event to the respected socket by finding it with the id of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I use below approach to achieve this goal:

client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8183/?clientId='+clientId,{"force new connection":true});
```

server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("url"+socket.handshake.url);
    clientId=socket.handshake.query.clientId;
    console.log("connected clientId:"+clientId);

});
```

reference:https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing#global-authorization